# Get two values returned from class

Tags: php

I am trying to understand object oriented PHP programming and wrote a small class to learn. I am having trouble understanding why its not working the way I intend. I have two variables inside the class method `hello()` `$result` and `$test`. I am trying to access the data that is stored in those two variables and print it to the screen. I know I can just call an echo inside the method but I am trying to get it to echo outside of it.

What I get printed to the screen is `88` it does not print out the second variable `$test`. I am trying to understand why thats happening. My lack of understanding probably shows in the code.

```
<?php

class simpleClass{

    public function hello($result,$test) {
        $result = 4+4;
        $test = 10+5;
        return $result;
        return $test;
    }
}

$a = new simpleClass;
echo $a->hello();
echo $a->hello($result, $test);

?>
```

Comment: You can't return twice.

Comment: "If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function,..." You can read mote about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**parameter referencing**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) :

```
class simpleClass{

    public function hello(&$result, &$test) {
        $result = 4+4;
        $test = 10+5;
    }
}

$a = new simpleClass;
$result=''; $test='';

$a->hello($result, $test);

echo $result;
echo '<br>';
echo $test;
```

> 8
>   15

To clarify, when you add `&` to a function param, the value of that param - if you change or manipulate it inside the function - is handled back to your original variable passed. So you dont even have to return a result, and lets say pack it into an `array` or `stdObject` and unpack it afterwards. But you can still return something from the function, eg

```
$ok = $a->hello($result, $test);
```

as a flag to indicate if the calculation went right, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

you can return a `list` or `array`

```
public function hello($result,$test) {
        $result = 4+4;
        $test = 10+5;
        return array($result, $test);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multiple `return` statements in the same function because of the way `return` works. When a `return` statement is encountered the function stops executing there and then, passing back to the caller. The rest of the function never runs.

Answer (score 1):

The complicated answer is to use a model.

```
class simpleResultTestModel {
    public $result;
    public $test;
    public function __construct($result,$test) {
        $this->result = $result;
        $this->test = $test;
    }
}

class simpleClass {
    public function hello($result=4, $test=10) {
        $result = $result+4;
        $test = $test+5;
        return new simpleResultTestModel($result, $test);
    }
}
```

This way, you know `simpleClass->hello()` will always return an instance of `simpleResultTestModel`.

Also, I updated your hello method definition. You have two parameters, but don't actually apply them; I took the liberty of setting default values and then used them in the computation.

Usage:

```
$a = new simpleClass();

$first = $a->hello();
echo $first->result;
echo $first->test;

$second = $a->hello($first->result,$first->test);
echo $second->result;
echo $second->test;
```

I would try to stay away from passing by reference (especially within a class definition) unless you have a legitimate reason for doing so. It is bad practice when creating instances of classes (i.e. "sticky values" if you will).